# Get generic container without @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Tags: java

I try to avoid `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` when possible, but I don't find any solution for this case.

Let a **Container**:

```java
public final class Container<Y>
{
    public final Class<Y> type;

    public Container(Class<Y> type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Now, from a list of containers `List<Container<?>> containers;`, I want to get & cast one:

```java
private <Y> Container<Y> containerOf(Class<Y> type)
{
    for (var container : containers)
    {
        if (container.type == type)
        {
            return (Container<Y>) container;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Of course, `(Container<Y>) container` requires a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. Do you have a solution for this case ? I can change the Container class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to suppress an unchecked cast warning, provided you can actually guarantee that it is safe (e.g. by construction).

If it is guaranteed to be the case that a `Container`'s type parameter matches the type of its `type` field, then this would be safe.

If that's the case, add the suppression, but it is a good idea to document why you believe it to be safe:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Safe because ...
Container<T> result = (Container<Y>) container;
return result;
```

Also, extracting a variable is a good idea, because it means you can suppress just on that variable, rather than putting it on the method/class and then suppressing any and all unchecked warnings in the whole method.